# ColorFunction still interferes with PlotLegends in Mathematica 10?

Tags: plotting, color

I want to draw 2 functions in the same plot and I use `Show` for this. I am using Mathematica 10 and I still have the problem that the legend disappears for the `Plot` in which I use `ColorFunction`. The workarounds proposed in the meantime for version 9 doesn't seem to work for me...

```
plot1 = Plot[100*x, {x, 0, 500}, 
        PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Black, Thickness[0.007]}, 
        PlotRange -> {{0, 500*1.1}, {All, All}}, 
        PlotLegends -> {Style["   A-range", Black]}];

plot2 = Plot[100*x, {x, 200, 520}, 
        PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.03], Opacity[0.5]}, 
        ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, ColorData["DarkRainbow"][y]], 
        PlotLegends -> LineLegend["DarkRainbow", "   W-range"], 
        PlotTheme -> "Scientific"];
Show[plot1, plot2]
```

[image]

Is there something I can do about this (or I am just doing (again) a simple syntax mistake)?

Comment: Simple syntax mistake `LineLegend[{"DarkRainbow", "   W-range"}]`

Comment: I think Conrad wants `LineLegend[{"DarkRainbow"}, {"   W-range"}]` to use "DarkRainbow" as the color and "   W-range" as the label.

Comment: @JackLaVigne: You're right, this was my intention.

Comment: @Hubble07: Can you post your comment as answer, so that I will be able to mark it as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error appears due to a simple syntax error in `PlotLegends` for `plot2`. The correct syntax should be as follows:

```
  PlotLegends -> LineLegend[{"DarkRainbow"}, {" W-range"}]
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not that much in the ColorFunction, but in the curly braces that are needed to be put inside the `LineLegend` statement. Then the `PlotTheme` should be equal in the both plots, or no at all. Try this:

```
    plot1 = Plot[100*x, {x, 0, 500}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Black, Thickness[0.007]}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 500*1.1}, {All, All}}, 
   PlotLegends -> {Style["   A-range", Black]}];

plot2 = Plot[100*x, {x, 200, 520}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.03], Opacity[0.5]}, 
   ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, ColorData["DarkRainbow"][y]], 
   PlotLegends -> LineLegend[{"        W-range"}]];

Show[plot1, plot2]
```

[image]

One problem with it is that Mma does not know that you might want to show the whole rainbow, and only shows its small part.

Have fun!